# Meaning and origin of "the grind of my day"

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

Somebody told me today in chat:

> before i get into **the grind of my day**... is there anything you are waiting on from us or need asap?

What does the expression *the grind of my day* mean? Where does it come from?

Comment: It might be helpful if you googled 'Daily Grind' there are dictionary.com and wikipedia references to it.

Comment: @Steve: "grind of my day" doesn't lead to searching for "daily grind" unless you know what you're looking for

Comment: @simchona I intended for my comment to be helpful. It was not a comment on the quality of the question. Though I see how it could be interpreted the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the colloquial definitions of *grind* is (from the Oxford English Dictionary):

> Steady hard work; labour of a monotonous kind, esp. close and hard study; an instance of this, a dull and laborious task.

The first written use of this is:

> 1851    B. H. Hall Coll. College Words,   Grind, an exaction; an oppressive action. Students speak of a very long lesson which they are required to learn, or of anything which is very unpleasant or difficult to perform as a grind.

So the *grind of one's day* would be the daily, monotonous work that one has to do. It is more common to refer to this as the [daily grind](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daily+grind).

Answer (score 2):

It's a variation on the more common form *the [daily grind](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daily+grind)*, which means:

> **Definition:**    everyday routine, esp. monotonous
>   **Example:**    The daily grind was starting to get to her.
>   **Usage:**      slang

Comment: +1 for short & to the point. OP's example is simply a (somewhat misguided, IMHO) variant of a common slang expression.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to mean, "Can I do something for you quickly (that needs done), before I get to the "grind" (longest part) of my day, and am therefore unavailable to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I have always assume that it is a metaphor. When you grind metal (or whatever), you wear bits off gradually. Each pass of the grinder takes off a tiny amount of metal, but over a long time a lot is worn away.

The metaphor for work can go both ways:

- Negative: Hard work uses up your energy and your enthusiasm, but not all in one go. It's ground away gradually over hours, months or years
- Positive: You may not achieve much in a day, but by grinding away at your tasks, you gradually achieve something

Note that the metaphor also applies to "grinding" in role-playing games; gradually building up your character's stats by taking part in minor battles etc.

Answer (score 0):

Daily Grind - when common people had to grind their own corn, barley to make bread and stews using a grind stone.  It took a long time to grind enough and was the Daily Grind.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Lynaire!  Please cite any resources to substantiate your answer.

Comment: It sounds too obvious not to have been mentioned. Perhaps no one could find anything to support the theory.

Comment: Bear with, I shall come back to this.  As  newby I need to catch breath.

Comment: Ruth Goldman, Historian, working on Guedelon Castle in Treigny, France.  She demonstrated the use of the 'home' grain grinder as used by people working far from commercial mills.